# Rendering nested data in Admin on Rest

Tags: firebase, admin-on-rest

I am trying to figure out how to render nested data from Firebase into AOR. I'm using the firebase aor client, but i'm not sure how I should render the data.

Firebase Schema

```
connections
   userId
     connectingUserId
        initiatingUser
        note
        status
```

App.js

```
const App = () => (
    <Admin restClient={RestClient(trackedResources, config.firebaseConfig)}>

        <Resource name="connections" list={ConnectionsList} icon={UserIcon} />
    </Admin>
);
```

I would like to be able to render something like the following, but I'm not sure how

```
             <Datagrid>
                  <ReferenceField label="User" source="id" reference="users">
                      <TextField source="fullName" />
                  </ReferenceField>
                  <ReferenceField label="ConnectingUser" source="connectingUserId" reference="users">
                      <TextField source="fullName" />
                  </ReferenceField>
                  <ReferenceField label="InitiatingUser" source="initiatingUser" reference="users">
                      <TextField source="fullName" />
                  </ReferenceField>
                  <TextField source="note" />
                  <TextField source="status" />
                  <EditButton />
              </Datagrid>
```